# How to automatically export stored procedures for a release SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, automation, build-automation

Our team was releasing a new version of our system yesterday and we came across some issues with stored procedures. To cut a long story short we had to upload the old stored procedures to fix the issues.

I have now been given the task to automatically back up the stored procedures for our database before we release a build. I have went through a lot of sites and I've looked at generating scripts, making batch files, doing whole backups and scheduling tasks etc but none of these solutions would automatically backup only the stored procedures.

Any help in this case would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Best Regards
Ryan

Answer (score 9):

In Management Studio, right click on your database in the Object Explorer window, go to Tasks -> Generate Scripts... and follow the wizard.

Comment: We where already doing this, it will not automate the process. We are constantly having to do new releases and I want to get this process automated so we don't have to do it every time. Thanks for your answer all the same, it should help someone.

Comment: Look into Powershell for this type of automation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SMO libraries to create your scripts and use them in command line batch files. Read more in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx

Comment: I really like the idea of using this kind of a set up, I will see what I can come up with and I will post it here. Thanks DiRaTT

Answer (score 0):

Before run de script generator, set Option Continue scripting on Error, otherwise script will not be gereated.
If option DROP and Create is chosen, set option Script Object-Levels permission for stored procedures

Answer (score 0):

Is your software source code checked into source control? It might be of benefit if your database is as well. This is the method software has used to manage versions and releases for years, and its about time DB's joined the party.

I suggest you look into a database project (available in the current 2015 free version of SQL Server Data Tools), which is a way of checking your objects in and out of a repository etc. It's a more complete way of managing database objects and fits into the software lifecycle. You can release your database codebase in conjunction with your software codebase and manage it all in one.